# Reinstall libprotobuf.so files in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

Tags: protocol-buffers

While encountering problems updating protobuf to 3.1 I foolishly ended up removing the libprotbuf* files in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

Fortunately Protoc --version now outputs "libprotoc 3.1.0", but I am now trying to get the libprotobuf.so files back. When trying to use things that link to protobuf like matplotlib.pyplot I get an error like

> ** (process:15246): WARNING **: Failed to load shared library 'libgdk-3.so.0' referenced by the typelib: libprotobuf-lite.so.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have been able to reinstall some of libprotobuf files but the .so files are still missing.

```
$ ll /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf*

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.3M Oct 23  2015 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 387K Oct 23  2015 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   25 Oct 23  2015 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so -> libprotobuf-lite.so.9.0.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Oct 23  2015 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so -> libprotobuf.so.9.0.1
```

Anyone know a way to recover the protobuf.so.9.0.1 and libprotobuf-lite.so.9.0.1 files in ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 3):

Build **Protobuf 2.6.1** version. After building this version it will create **libprotobuf.so.9.0.1** and **libprotobuf-lite.so.9.0.1**.

Answer (score 0):

download the right protobuf version, build it yourself, and you will be just fine.
the original so and the so you are going to build should be the same, the later one will work just fine.